# Why is Netanyahu still in power in Israel after the 7th October attack?

Tags: israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war

From an external perspective, it seems that Netanyahu and his various governments since 2008 [were responsible](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/nov/21/the-netanyahu-doctrine-how-israels-longest-serving-leader-reshaped-the-country-in-his-image) for a lot of mistakes which led to the 7th October attack by Hamas having terrible consequences, both in the past in terms of diplomacy and security policy, and in recent decisions before the attack:

- He dismissed [any form of discussion with Palestinians](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/sep/11/arab-leaders-denounce-netanyahu-plan-annex-palestinian-territories-israel), causing more anger and desperation for them, probably encouraging some of them into violent action, since they had no other option.
- He initiated a security policy relying entirely on technological military superiority to maintain control on Gaza. The goal was to ignore Palestinians and to make Israeli [able to live oblivious of the conflict](https://time.com/6322410/how-netanyahu-undermined-israel-security/). He touted this as a [perfect solution for Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mowing_the_grass), and  this proved to be precisely a major weakness in the attack.
- He [favoured Hamas over the Palestinian Authority](https://thehill.com/opinion/international/4268794-the-symbiotic-relationship-between-netanyahu-and-hamas/) in power in Gaza and touted this as a major success for Israel, since this gave the government a [good excuse not to have any discussion](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/netanyahu-israel-gaza-hamas-1.7010035) with Palestinians.
- His government encourages the colonization of the West Bank by settlers, and the violence resulting from this policy required [some of the IDF redeployed](https://www.timesofisrael.com/more-details-unveiled-of-idf-intel-on-oct-7-plans-consults-hours-before-hamas-attack/) to protect the settlers. As a result military defenses around Gaza were weak, a weakness exploited by Hamas (Hamas itself [didn't even expect so few defense forces](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/1/21/hamas-says-october-7-attack-was-a-necessary-step-admits-to-some-faults)).
- There was also a [major intelligence failure](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/11/30/world/middleeast/israel-hamas-attack-intelligence.html) under his government, where the Hamas plan was known but deemed irrealistic.
- His reluctance to negotiate with Hamas about [freeing the remaining hostages](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67248317) is hard to understand, especially since the all-out war on Gaza doesn't seem to [make their release more likely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war_hostage_crisis).

It seems clear that Netanyahu's governments took many decisions which contributed to the Hamas attack having such a terrible impact. Additionally, Netanyahu himself has an obvious conflict of interest due to his [legal troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_of_Benjamin_Netanyahu), so he might not take decisions in the best interest of the country.
In a democracy, a leader who is responsible for the difficulties of the country is usually replaced. His departure is openly asked by some of the Israeli population and by several [Israeli](https://www.aspistrategist.org.au/hubris-meets-nemesis-in-israel/) [leaders](https://www.foreignaffairs.com/israel/why-netanyahu-must-go).

So why is Netanyahu still in charge?

Comment: "They [Palestinians] had no other option" - how about joining the Abraham Accords?

Comment: "In a democracy, a leader who is responsible for the difficulties of the country is usually replaced." Has there been an election in Israel since October?

Comment: Voting to close: "The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or **discredit** a specific political cause, group or politician."

Comment: @TimurShtatland Imho you confuse 'discrediting' with 'criticizing'.  The difference is in whether the claims are backed with evidence or not. If we remove all the questions and answers on PoliticsSE which contain any criticism of anybody, we can close the site.

Comment: @Erwan the reasons that you give are the reasons why Israelis might decide not to vote for Netanyahu, but they are not the reasons why he is still in power - which has to do with how and when one organizes the elections. So, strictly speaking, you are trying to argue against Netanyahu (i.e., promoting a cause), although the basic question is legitimate.

Comment: I don't understand why this post got downvoted.

Comment: @Jacob3 apparently you cite the he [Abraham Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Accords) without knowing that they were two bilateral agreements between Israel UAE and Bahrein. Palestinians themselves were purposefully ignored in these deals, they didn't have any say.

Comment: @Erwan, The Palestinians are not a side in the Abraham Accords, because they don't want "peace for peace" - which is the essence of the Abraham Accords.

Comment: @Jacob3 you're making stuff up as you go. Palestinians were purposefully not involved by Israel in the Abraham Accords, since the goal was to normalize relations with some Arab countries without while bypassing Palestinians.

Comment: The answer to the question obviously is that his term is not up and there hasn't been an election since October. This is actually quite typical for elected prime ministers, presidents and other officials.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In a democracy, a leader who is responsible for the difficulties of the country is usually replaced. His departure is openly asked by some of the Israeli population and by several Israeli leaders.
>
> So why is Netanyahu still in charge?

In a democracy there are also established procedures for removing the government (or the head of the government), and electing/appointing the new one. Note also that Israel is a parliamentary democracy - it is not Netanyahu alone who gives orders, as in the US, but his actions should necessarily have the accord of the government, composed of representatives of several political parties.

In Israel the government is removed either when its term expires or earlier, if it loses the majority support, which is technically expressed by a non-confidence vote. Indeed, [such a vote was held a few days ago](https://www.timesofisrael.com/no-confidence-motion-against-netanyahu-fails-in-knesset-with-only-18-votes-in-favor/) and failed to remove the government - for obvious reason that the current government is the [*national unity government*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_war_cabinet), formed after October 7 out of the parties that had been in Netanyahu's previous government and the major opposition parties.

In other words, the elected representatives of the Israeli people think that, due to the current challenges facing their country, the time is unsuitable for holding new elections. Had Netanyahu failed in October to bring the opposition to the government, he would have likely faced a non-confidence vote and the elections. It is also expected that the government would fall after the major phase of the war against Hamas is over.

Note that the situation is not unlike in Ukraine, where the Presidential election scheduled for this Spring would be likely postponed:

> In November 2023, Zelenskyy said "now is not the right time for elections" and asked the Parliament to approve an extension of martial law for another 90 days, until 14 February 2024. A poll released by KIIS that same month reported that 80% of Ukrainians do not want to have an election until the war is over. In November 2023, all political parties represented in the Verkhovna Rada signed a document in which they agreed to postpone holding any national election until after the end of martial law and agreed to work on a special law that would regulate the first post-war election, which would take place no earlier than six months after the cancellation of martial law.

Answer (score 4):

Because the next elections in Israel is set for about 3 years from now. And no party of the government is interested to call for new elections in the middle of a war.

Besides this, many Israeli's don't think that those accusations against him are factual. There are many indications that the situation would have been much worse, if not for Netanyahu's policies.

Comment: *There are many indications that the situation would have been much worse*  : which would be very nice to see sourced and linked here.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, The whole issue here is hypothetical. Based on the idea that if only Israel would have been softer on the Palestinians, the Palestinians would have been much less violent. One could easily say the exact opposite; Gaza is the outcome of Israel's softness, if Israel would have treated Gaza like the West Bank (including settlements, which ensures feet on the ground), Hamas would be today no worse than the trouble-makers in Jenin.

Comment: @Jacob3 But the thing is, Netanhayu needed Hamas and made everything he could for them. Netanyahu needs some israelian deads from time to time to continue the status quo; a pacified Gaza is not in his interest. If Gaza joined the non-violent way of the PLO, Israel would lose the US umbrella and could not continue to forestall the calls for a two-state solution. Hamas realized that killing two or three israelians every few months was playing into Bibi's hands, and went for a number that was way harder to swallow, but in a controlled Gaza, the Mossad would have to pretend being Hamas.

Comment: @Rekesoft, Giving in to Qatari pressure to transfer money to "poor people" in Gaza, "under the auspices of the UN", does not mean "Netanhayu needed Hamas and made everything he could for them".

Comment: @Jacob3 Fyi there are many reports of Netanhayu congratulating himself for the success of having Hamas in power in Gaza. It was his official strategy, see [here](https://www.timesofisrael.com/for-years-netanyahu-propped-up-hamas-now-its-blown-up-in-our-faces/), [here](https://thehill.com/opinion/international/4268794-the-symbiotic-relationship-between-netanyahu-and-hamas/), [here](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/nov/21/the-netanyahu-doctrine-how-israels-longest-serving-leader-reshaped-the-country-in-his-image)...

Comment: @Erwan, Netanyahu didn't choose to strengthen the PA (Fatah) so they can overthrow Hamas, because diplomatic and pragmatic [supporters of] terrorists aren't so much better than active terrorists. Indeed the US absorbs critisism for the exact opposite, for supporting [then] "peaceful" terrorists against active enemies, until they were supported enough to become unpeaceful - like the Mujahadeen. The PA could also turn to commit on their own the terrorism they are so dearly supporting, once they get strong enough.

Comment: @Jacob3 you make an interpretative and convoluted argument but there's no  need: Netanyahu himself said that he favored Hamas, and it was perfectly consistent with his strategy to conflate Palestinians with terrorists in order to avoid continuing the peace process.